# ParsingMethod for Array of Edit Texts android

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, android-edittext

My app has 4-5 EditTexts on each activity and I have 10 or so activities. I need to parse each of these to a double. So I figured I want to create a method in which I enter an EditText Array and it returns a double array with the parsed numbers.

One of the EditTexts will always be empty so I would need that specific position in the array of Doubles that are supposed to be returned to 0.

This is what I have been fiddling around with (without success so far).

```
public double[] parser(EditText[] editArray) {
            EditText toBeParsed[] = null;
            double parsed[] = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < editArray.length; i++) {
                try {
                    parsed[i] = Double.parseDouble(toBeParsed[i].getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    parsed[i] = 0;}
            }
```

Ho do i need to set this up?

Next in one of my activities I  have this where I call the method (from a MiscMethods.java file)

```
EditText inputs[] = {i1,i2,i3,i4}
Double parsed[];
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                parsed[i] = MiscMethods.parser(inputs);
            }
```

But get a type mismatch... Why? the method returns an array of doubles and should put them into the double parsed[] array.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using toBeParsed array in stead of your editArray

so

```
parsed[i] = Double.parseDouble(toBeParsed[i].getText().toString());
```

should be

```
parsed[i] = Double.parseDouble(editArray[i].getText().toString());
```

Comment: thanks, what do I set as return? parsed[] gives a compile error type mismatch

Comment: edited a question about how to use the result :) please help again

Comment: for(Double value : parsed) {   /** do something with value **/ }

Comment: I just need the parsed[] array to be filled with the double[] coming from the method. what do i put in the loop?